# Note taking app that syncs with the cloud and lets me create a shortcut to a specific saved note?

Tags: applications, notes, simplenote

I'm looking for note taking app that does the following:

1. Syncs with a cloud based account (like simplenote)
2. Keeps a local version of each note (I dont want to have to wait for it to download each time, or not be able to access it if I'm offline).
3. Allows me to create a shortcut to a specific note
4. Goes directly into edit mode when the note is opened.  I don't want to have to click "edit" from a Read Only view.

I've already tried all the apps listed here: http://simplenoteapp.com/downloads/ and they all open in edit mode which is nice, but none of them let me create a shortcut to a specific note.  Evernote does do this, however, it opens notes in Read Only view by default and I have a massive Evernote archive so I don't want to keep local notebooks with that app.  Catch and AK Pad also only open in Read Only mode.

**Basically if it's in the market I've seen it so I don't need suggestions of apps to check out.  I'm looking for suggestions of apps that you know fit the specific criteria layed out above.**

Comment: I assume by "shortcut" you mean a shortcut on the home screen?

Comment: yes, but not necessarily just on the home screen.  I use some apps that let me place shortcuts in other places like the menu bar and in a popup...  Basically, I'm looking for something that adds the option to the "Shortcut" context menu.

Comment: Haven't found one. I've got an app that does 1, 2, and 4, but that shortcut thing is tricky. You should probably contact some of these Simplenote app devs and ask 'em for that feature.

Comment: Yeah, I think I may have to do that.  I have found apps that do 1, 2 & 4 or 2,3 & 4, or 1, 2 & 3 but none that hit them all.

Answer (score 1):

I am using [Springpad](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.springpad) which meets all of your requirements apart from 4. But you can long press and select edit which sort of works like you want it to.

Comment: Thanks but there's a lot of solutions that meet 3 out of the 4 criteria.  I've used Springpad and it's a good app but doesn't suit my needs.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, but maybe Tomdroid. Not sure about 3. Or maybe soon if you ask for it on their site?